# How to list the table name from sqlite DB -- Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to android sqlite. i want to get list of table residing in one particular database. Is this possible in sqlite. Can anyone guide me on this. I searched long time for this, dint get any idea.

For example :
My dB name is ABC, in that i have 10 different tables, i want to get the list of table names from that particular Db. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pull the DB from the device through file explorer. Install SQLite manager as plugin to the browser (Firefox). Then open your DB through SQLite manager.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the `sqlite_master` table of the schema `ABC` .

```
SELECT * FROM ABC.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```